# Scatter with Straight Lines and markers with Highchart

Tags: highcharts, javascript-objects

[image]

How do I arrange the data format (in JSON) to be consumed as depicts above

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done in this demo? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hvt2fj9m/

Comment: almost... but is it possible to place the y axis in the middle

Comment: You can achieve it by setting the offset to some negative value, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fruq367p/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset